# Set days name as per the language localization

Tags: xamarin, datepicker, localization

I am facing an issue with showing day names as per the selected language. I have already set the locale parameter. As you can see in the attached screenshot, I am able to convert the month name. However, days are still showing in the English language only. Can anyone help please?

```
var modalPicker = new ModalPickerViewController(ModalPickerType.Date, AppResource.Date_Title, recordController)
            {
                HeaderBackgroundColor = UIColor.FromRGB(237, 237, 237),
                HeaderTextColor = UIColor.FromRGB(109, 109, 109),
                ModalPresentationStyle = UIModalPresentationStyle.Custom
            };

            
            modalPicker.DatePicker.Locale = new Foundation.NSLocale("es");
            modalPicker.DatePicker.Mode = UIDatePickerMode.Date;
            NSDate preSelectedDate = GetFormattedDate(textField.Text, "MM/dd/yyyy");

modalPicker.OnModalPickerDismissed += (s, ea) =>
            {

            };
        
                recordController.PresentViewController(modalPicker, true, null);
```

[image]

Comment: Do you mean that set the "MON TUE ..." to another language? It depends on the language you selected in "Language&Region".

Comment: @KyleWang-MSFT Yes I want to convert "MON, TUE" according to the language. But I am unable to do so. If you can help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Generally, the language of the "UIDatePicker" will change according to the system language you choose. You don’t need to write code manually to modify it.

But if you want to set another language "es-ES" for UIDatePicker, you can create a new string key `Localization native development region` in the Info.plist file and set it to `es-ES`.

[image]

Comment: Hey, I need further help from you, whenever I am trying to change the value of this parameter at a run time then it requires force restart of the application. Then only the language change reflect in calendar and number formate in the app otherwise not. Do you have any solution for this? that without force restart I can update the language in the application.